# Spark Streaming - Is it possible to consume a specific partition of Kafka Topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to consume a specific partition of a Kafka topic using Spark Streaming.

I don't see any methods for this use case in [KafkaUtils](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-8/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.scala) class.

There is a method called `createRDD`, which is basically expecting `offsets` and it is useful only for non-streaming applications. Is there any other way can i consume a specific partition of Kafka topic using Spark Streaming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to consume a single partition, the most granular we can work with is a topic. But, there is a way to specify that say that a given message was originated from a specific partition. You can do this when using the overload of `createDirectStream` which takes a `Function1[MessageAndMetadata, R]`.

For example, let's assume we have a key and message of type `String`, and that we're currently only consuming from a single topic. We can do:

```
val topicAndPartition: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long] = ???
val kafkaProperties: Map[String, String] = ???

KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String,
                              String, 
                              StringDecoder,
                              StringDecoder,
                              (String, String)](
        streamingContext,
        kafkaConfig.properties,
        topicAndPartition,
        (mam: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) =>
          (mam.partition, mam.message())
```

This way, I'm outputting a tuple of a partition (1) and the underlying message (2). Then, I can filter this `DStream[(String, String)]` to contain only messages from a specific partition:

```
val filteredStream = kafkaDStream.filter { case (partition, _) => partition == 4 }
```

If we're consuming from multiple topics, we'll need to output a tuple of both topic and partition in order to filter the partition with the right topic. Luckily, there's already a handy case class called `TopicAndPartition` we can use. We'd have:

```
(mam: MessageAndMetadata[String, String]) => 
  (TopicAndPartition(mam.topic(), mam.partition()), mam.message())
```

And then:

```
val filteredStream = kafkaDStream.filter { 
   case (tap, _) => tap.topic == "mytopic" && tap.partition == 4 
}
```